# Wordpress add user number field in contact information part

Tags: wordpress, user-profile

I am wondering how to achieve the following.
I try to create a number field input in the wordpress user profile under contact information.

So far if i use show_user_profile & edit_user_profile hooks, the field will appear on the bottom of the profile page.

Is it possible to create a number field under the contact information part (standard in wordpress?)

I tried to add different priorities to the actions, but that didnt solve it.

So far i have the following:

```
function addurenuser(){
    $userid = get_current_user_id();
    if ( current_user_can('update_plugins',$userid)){ ?>
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
            <th>
            <label>Uren</label>
                </th>
                <td>
            <input type="number" name="uren" id="uren" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'uren', $user->ID ) ); ?>">
            </td>
            </tr>
</table> <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'addurenuser' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'addurenuser' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
function addurenuser()
  {
    echo '<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".your-custom-field").insertAfter($(".user-email-wrap").closest("table"));
    });
    </script>';
    $userid = get_current_user_id();
    if (current_user_can('update_plugins', $userid)) { ?>
    <table class="form-table your-custom-field">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <label>Uren</label>
        </th>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="uren" id="uren" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('uren', $userid->ID)); ?>">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table> <?php
                }
              }
              add_action('show_user_profile', 'addurenuser');
              add_action('edit_user_profile', 'addurenuser');
```